# Replace '/' with '-'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the format of a date in a string from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `mm-dd-yyyy`.

I have tried using the following but it does not work

```
str.replace(///g,"-");
```

Comment: use for-loop, it would work faster than regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `/` delimits the regular expression, if you want to use a `/` character as data within one, you must escape it:

```
/\//g
```

Comment: But this '//' ends up commenting all the thing following g..

Comment: @user2130674 — No, it doesn't. It might look that way if you have a syntax highlighter that doesn't understand JavaScript properly.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems :

- you need to escape the `/` in the regex
- replace returns a new string and doesn't change the old one (strings are immutable)

Use

```
str = str.replace(/\//g, "-")
```

Answer (score 0):

it works.

```
'12/5/13'.replace(/\//g, '-');
```